# how to solve a inequality?

Tags: inequality

I have to prove the following inequality with induction from $(n-1)$ to $n$:

$(n+1)! \geq 2^n$

I know the solution, but I can't figure out where the $2$ came from:

$\begin{aligned}(n+1)! &= (n+1) \cdot n! & \\ &\ge (n+1) \cdot 2^{n-1} & \\ & \ge  \color{orange}{2} \cdot 2^{n-1} & \leftarrow \text{Here} \\ & \ge  2^n\end{aligned}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $2$ came simply from the fact that $n+1\ge2$ for any $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 0):

So by the inductive hypothesis, we know that $n! \geq 2^{n}$. Now for the inductive step, we multiply both sides by $(n+1)$ to get $(n+1)! \geq 2^{n}(n+1)$. As $n + 1 > 2$, we have $(n+1)! \geq 2^{n+1}$.

Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 0):

No need for induction. RHS is the product of $n$ numbers all of them 2. LHS is also a product of $n$ numbers  from 2 to $(n+1)$. So definitely LHS is bigger.